# expected one of [String, Regexp], got 1:Fixnum (TypeError) in page-object

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to find an image and i am using an if condition with image `exists?` then performing a delete operation. If not then addition. I am getting the following error when doing so..

### HTML:

```
<div class="xicGridViewport">
<table id="patetrnGrid-100228" class="xicGrid xicGridLoaded" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="id328" class=" xicGridRow0">
                    <td>
                        <td>
                            <td>
                                <td>
                                    <td>
                                        <td>
                                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                    <a id="cellIconLink2a" href="#" onclick="var wcall=wicketSubmitFormById('form9', '?wicket:interface=:0:form:multiplePatternBuilderGroupBox:patternGroupbox:patetrnGrid:gridCheckGroup:xicGridContainer:xicGrid:rows:3:cells:8:cell:cellIconLink::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true', 'multiplePatternBuilderGroupBox:patternGroupbox:patetrnGrid:gridCheckGroup:xicGridContainer:xicGrid:rows:3:cells:8:cell:cellIconLink' ,null,null, function() {return Wicket.$$(this)&&Wicket.$$('form9')}.bind(this));;; return false;">
                                                        <img class="xicIcon xicIconLoaded xicIconDelete" xic:size="S" xic:icon="delete" src="/uit/xicola/2.3/img/spacer.png"> <!-- Here, where i am using if condition -->
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

### Code:

`pattern_builder_page.rb`

```
        class BuilderPage
        include PageObject

        text_field(:area, name: /area/)
        select_list(:load_type, name: /loadType/)
        checkbox(:link_power, name: /linkPower/)
        image(:plus, css: ".xicIcon.xicIconLoaded.xicIconAdd")
        image(:delete_icon, css: ".xicIcon.xicIconLoaded.xicIconDelete")
        button(:delete, text: 'Delete')

        def create_pattern(category, place, destination)
            train_category_element.when_present
            self.train_category = category
            fac_place_element.when_present
            self.fac_place = place
            fac_destination_element.when_present
            self.fac_destination = destination
            wait_element.when_not_visible
            refresh_element.when_present
            refresh
            wait_element.when_not_visible
            if delete_icon_element.exists?
                delete
                yes_element.when_present.click
            end
    end
end
```

### Error:

```
    expected one of [String, Regexp], got 1:Fixnum (TypeError)
      ./lib/pages/pattern_builder_page.rb:22:in `create_pattern'
      ./features/step_definitions/bulk_steps.rb:30:in `/^I select "(.*?)", "(.*?)" and "(.*?)" facility and submit$/'
      features\pattern_builder.feature:11:in `When I select "<category>",
 "<place>" and "<destination>" facility and submit'
```

Comment: The exception seems to be pretty clear - you are passing a number to a method that expects a string or regexp. If you try creating a code example that reproduces your problem (as the code here is not sufficient), the problem will be much more clear.

Comment: It would help to give the full stack trace of the error, which shows exactly where the exception is being raised. However, based on the message, it is likely coming from Watir-Webdriver's ElementLocator. Basically one of the values you are passing to locate an element is a number, which is only allowed when locating by `:index`. For example, you have something like `browser.div(:id => 1).text`.

Comment: You still need to show more code. The exception is related to code in a step definition, which we cannot see. I assume it does some stuff related to the BuilderPage create_pattern method, but I do not see how that method would work given that most of the elements used are not defined.

Comment: Thanks, Justin for providing the solution in the second comment. I have gone through the all my code and in my common page module. I have defined the locator wrongly ie., instead of `(index: 1)` I used `(xpath: 1)`. Can u please add the second comment as an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception message, it is coming from [Watir-Webdriver's ElementLocator](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb#L155-L168):

```
VALID_WHATS = [String, Regexp]

def check_type(how, what)
  case how
  when :index
    unless what.kind_of?(Fixnum)
      raise TypeError, "expected Fixnum, got #{what.inspect}:#{what.class}"
    end
  else
    unless VALID_WHATS.any? { |t| what.kind_of? t }
      raise TypeError, "expected one of #{VALID_WHATS.inspect}, got #{what.inspect}:#{what.class}"
    end
  end
end
```

This method shows that locator values can only be numeric for `:index` locators.

This implies that in one of your locators, you are passing a number for a locator that is not `:index`. For example you have:

```
# An invalid accessor:
div(:field_name, :id => 1)

# Or what is ultimately called by Watir-Webdriver:
browser.div(:id => 1).text
```

As per the comments, there was an `xpath: 1` locator instead of a `index: 1` locator.